# Converting floating-point values into a QImage

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I want to convert an image from `Mat` type in OpenCV that has floating-point values into a `QImage`.

I did it the other way (from QImage to Mat), and here is my code :

```
Mat qimage2mat(const QImage& qimage) {
    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(qimage.height(), qimage.width(), CV_8UC4, (uchar*)qimage.bits(), qimage.bytesPerLine());
    cv::Mat mat2 = cv::Mat(mat.rows, mat.cols, CV_8UC3 );
    int from_to[] = { 0,0,  1,1,  2,2 };
    cv::mixChannels( &mat, 1, &mat2, 1, from_to, 3 );
    return mat2;
}
```

How can I do it from Mat to QImage ?

Comment: where is the float value Mat? I inly see two byte value Mats...

Comment: my Mat type is basiclly filled with floating point number

Comment: Single channel? 3 channels? 4 channels?  which value range corresponds to which colors (white? red? blue? black?)?

Comment: it is a 4 channel,

Comment: use yourMat.convertTo with parameter CV_8UC4 then create QImage with foemat RGBA  8888 or sth. like that.maybe you have to rearrange channels and rescale the values first. depending on your mat